# Divs All Visible at Page Opening (despite of jquery, show div on radio button click)

Tags: html, jquery, checkbox, radio-button, visibility

Im trying to do; show divs when click on check-box radio button. I made it with jquery but when you load page all my divs are visible. You have to click my first check-box radio button to make other divs invisible. or just click other check-box radio buttons.

I tried

```
#row2 {
display:none;
```

}

But when I added this to css, if you click first check-box radio button(which is related to div row2) div is not visible and and it is not working.

Any other solution for when you open page I just want to see only div (row2) which is checked. I dont want to see other divs when page load.

Thanks...

Demo Link: https://rexin-demo.netlify.app/main.html

Ps: Pics and button are not visible on jsfiddled cuz of assets. Better to look it via demo link.

https://jsfiddle.net/t4e13xvj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger the click by adding `.filter(':checked').click()` at the end of the input's click event .. Try it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var inputValue = $(this).val(); // use .val() instead of .attr('value')
        var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
        $(".box").not(targetBox).hide();
        $(targetBox).show();
    }).filter(':checked').click();
});
```

Also I prefer to use `change` instead of `click` for radio and checkbox inputs

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').on('change' ,function(){
        if(this.checked){
          var inputValue = $(this).val();
          var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
          $(".box").not(targetBox).hide();
          $(targetBox).show();
        }
    }).filter(':checked').prop('checked' , true).change();
 });
```

**OR** With only css you can use

```
.box:not(.product){
  display : none;
}
```